# Kafka Cluster on EC2 facing "Shrinking ISR for partition" and "Cached zkVersion [] not equal to that in zookeeper, skip updating ISR"

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a 3 node kafka cluster built on `t2.medium` instances. Zookeeper and Broker are deployed in same ec2 instance. ec2 instances are spread across 3 diff av zones within a region.
The Setup is as following:

1. Zookeeper has following memory settings  : `export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx512M -Xms512M"`
2. Broker has following memory settings     : `export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms1G"`
3. `Kafka Version - 0.10.1.1` which is officially compliant with `spring-boot 1.5.10`
4. Zookeeper bundled with Kafka is being used for setup.

Traffic Pattern: The traffic is not high (may be 4 msgs/sec), however huge amount of messages (500 msgs/sec) can arrive in short bursts of time [2-3 mins].

Issues Facing:
1. The following gets reported in broker server.log

`INFO Partition [topic1,0] on broker 0: Shrinking ISR for partition [topic1,0] from 0,1,2 to 0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)`

`INFO Partition [topic1,0] on broker 0: Cached zkVersion [8] not equal to that in zookeeper, skip updating ISR (kafka.cluster.Partition)`

This makes the cluster unstable and until a rolling restart of all brokers (also zookeepers sometime) is performed, the cluster never recovers on it's own.

There is no noticeable nw issue when checked from Metrics available in AWS EC2 Console, except spike in traffic. Also nothing in logs from nw perspective, when the issue starts.
It looks like there is a GC run, at the time when it starts reporting and then continuously keeps reporting on `kafkaServer-GC.log`, until rolling restart of the whole cluster is performed.

1. What should be the correct instance type to handle this kind of scenario? What would be the ideal memory settings advisable? Is there any other configuration that can be corrected in this regard?
2. Is there a way to find out the problematic node?
3. How do we decide whether the broker restart alone can help, or all brokers needs to be restarted as well?
4. How do we decide whether the zookeeper restart also is needed, and/or all zookeeper instances needs restart as well? Is there a way to use 4 letter words with the `zookeeper-shell.sh` comes bundled with kafka?
5. What can be a proactive monitoring step to detect this occurrence early?

Some guidance is badly needed here and needless to mention it's Extremely Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Probably your traffic pick causes this problem and your broker loses in-sink status.
You need to fine tune some parameters, some of which are quoted in official documentation:

> As with most distributed systems automatically handling failures
> requires having a precise definition of what it means for a node to be
> "alive". For Kafka node liveness has two conditions
>
> - A node must be able to maintain its session with ZooKeeper (via ZooKeeper's heartbeat mechanism)
> - If it is a slave it must replicate the writes happening on the leader and not fall "too far" behind
>
> We refer to nodes satisfying these two conditions as being "in sync"
> to avoid the vagueness of "alive" or "failed". The leader keeps track
> of the set of "in sync" nodes. If a follower dies, gets stuck, or
> falls behind, the leader will remove it from the list of in sync
> replicas. The definition of, how far behind is too far, is controlled
> by the **replica.lag.max.messages** configuration and the definition of a
> stuck replica is controlled by the **replica.lag.time.max.ms**
> configuration.

Try also with your broker heap memory (see [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/21871/kafka-shrinkingexpanding-isr-for-partition-topic.html)).

About monitoring, through JMX you can watch a lot of metrics and among them, in particular:

**ISR shrink rate & ISR expansion rate**

Ref: https://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation/#ops

Comment: Thanks . I'll try out these properties. The link you referred for broker heap memory talks about ISR shrink rate and replica.* properties and not about memory. Did you really intend to use that link?

Comment: I intended also the comments in the link.